# GWT RPC: hotswap vs POJO

Tags: gwt, rpc

I have encountered following problem.

Currently I'm working with colleague on GWT project.
We are using RPC async service. We often need to send and receive `state` object which is a `HashMap`.

We have bunch of service methods which are always have state as parameter and as a return type:

```
HashMap<String, Serializable> fillAndGetUI(HashMap<String, Serializable> state) throws ProjectServiceException;
```

I'm telling not to use this because we have `Serializable` interface in method declaration which is not good for RPC and GWT compilation.

But: `HashMap` is useful while we can use hotswap instead of restarting server each time (it's enough to write method `put` and `get`). 
My suggestion was to use POJO, but we can loose hotswap abliliy which is critical.

What is the solution to not use `HashMap` in declarations and have Hotswap ability in the same time ? Can `RequestFactory` solve this issue? (We are using GWT 2.1. version change is not an option)

Comment: For developing you can still use HashMap, and for production POJO will be fine. And in this case it will be very useful to apply Command Pattern instead of RPC. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243423/why-use-the-command-pattern-in-gwt-or-any-web-app

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution use plain old RequestBuilder, JSON and Overlay Types. RequestFactory will not help you